# Running Mathematica inside the Subsystem of the Win 10 (WSL)

Tags: windows

There is no problem when installing the Mathematica inside the WSL. But there are several problems when launch mathematica in the shell. It displays:

```
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
pcilib: Cannot open /proc/bus/pci
lspci: Cannot find any working access method.
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/SystemFiles/Kernel/Binaries/Linux-x86-64/MathKernel: error while loading shared libraries: libippcc.so.8.1: cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Invalid argument
```

Does anyone have the experience of running mathematica successfully in the WSL? 
And how should I solve the shared libraries problem? (libippcc.so.8.1 does inside the Libraries directory of the mathematica, and also export the LD_LIBRARY_PATH does not help.)

Thanks very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know some have gotten the kernel running, but it requires setting up a few environment variables ahead of time.  As for the FrontEnd, it is not currently supported.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/faq

**Can I run ALL Linux apps in WSL?**
No! WSL is a tool aimed at enabling users who need them to run Bash and core Linux command-line tools on Windows. 
WSL does not aim to support GUI desktops or applications (e.g. Gnome, KDE, etc.)

Comment: Does this mean that the Developer Engine runs in WLS (or WSL2) without a problem?

Comment: @Shredderroy the kernel in the Developer Engine should run.  Anything that requires Graphics/Notebooks/etc... will be problematic, since those require a working FrontEnd.  Hard to say anything more beyond that, since its not something that we test against.